# python: how to replace strings in a nested list of strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace strings in a nested list.

```
board = [
['O', 'X', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'X'],
['.', 'O', 'X']
]
```

this should end up like

```
board = [
['O', '*', '.'],
['.', 'O', '*'],
['.', 'O', '*']
]
```

this is what ive tried:

```
    new_board = [[x.replace('X', '*') for x in l] for l in board]
```

it works like this as a single assingment like this but when i try do it in a function it doesnt work. The function must modify the given board in place; it returns None.

```
def change_player_char(board, player, new_char):

    board = [[new_char if j == player else j for j in i] for i in board]
```

I call it like:

```
board = [
['O', 'X', '.'],
['.', 'O', 'X'],
['.', 'O', 'X']
]

change_player_char(board, 'X', '*')
for row in board:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Not sure what doesn't work, but running your code gives `[['O', '*', '.'], ['.', 'O', '*'], ['.', 'O', '*']]` which appears to be what you want?

Comment: the code you use does work, double check it

Comment: So it turns out it works if I have it out of a function but when i try use it in a function it doesn't work, Updated OP.

Comment: You need to call it like this: `board = change_player_char(board, 'X', '*')`

Comment: The function must modify the given board in place; it returns None.

Answer (score 2):

```
[['*' if j=='X' else j for j in i] for i in board]
#[['O', '*', '.'], ['.', 'O', '*'], ['.', 'O', '*']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`:

```
board = [
 ['O', 'X', '.'],
 ['.', 'O', 'X'],
 ['.', 'O', 'X']
]
new_board = [list(map(lambda x:"*" if x == "X" else x, i)) for i in board]
```

Output:

```
[['O', '*', '.'], 
 ['.', 'O', '*'], 
 ['.', 'O', '*']]
```